# Showing formatted numeric values in input controls for large numbers

Tags: javascript, formatting, numbers, currency

I am trying to show large numbers on the html input with the help of some regex. 
As there is a limitation of javascript numbers of 17 digits, I cannot use the Number objects for showing the numbers whose precision is greater than 17. I have gone through the below SO reference

[How can I format numbers as money in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript)

but it seems to show unexpected values for numbers with precision more than 17 digits.

If someone has any idea of similar implementation, do let me know.

Comment: How are you trying to format these numbers? You are trying to do currency formatting of numbers representing quadrillions of dollars? As a general rule, though, from a UI perspective, if what you are trying to do is format the number as the user types it in, this is usually considered bad practice. It causes a disconnect between what the user has typed and what they see and can often be frustrating.

Comment: Hi torazaburo, I am using regex as specified in the above reference to convert numbers to currency formatted strings.